# Emberjs - Setting multiple models in a single route

Tags: ember.js

I have an Emberjs app that contains a dashboard on the main page, which is loaded by the /browse route. I need to select multiple models in the browse route, so I can assign them to several views I have on the page.

I'm able to retrieve the models using the code below, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong--even though the data is available within the respective template, I'm not sure how to reference the models outside of the templates.

How do I specify the model I need when I call setupController for each template on the dashboard? Do I even need to call setupController? I'm really trying to understand selecting, assigning, and managing models in Emberjs, so any advice is greatly apprectiated!

```
App.BrowseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
            sort: this.store.find('sort'),
            feature: this.store.find('feature'),
            category: this.store.find('category'),
            activity: this.store.find('activity')
        });
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('sort').set('model', this.sort);
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('feature').set('model', this.feature);
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('category').set('model', this.category);
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('activity').set('model', this.activity);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `controller.set('desiredModelName', model)` to set multiple models after the model hook has been resolved.

```
 App.BrowseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
                sort: this.store.find('sort'),
                feature: this.store.find('feature'),
                category: this.store.find('category'),
                activity: this.store.find('activity')
            });
        },
        setupController: function (controller, model) {
            this._super(controller, model);


            controller.set('sortModel', model.sort);
            controller.set('featureModel', model.feature);
            controller.set('categoryModel', model.category);
           controller.set('activityModel', model.activity);

        },

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is, I need to set the models on specific controllers, not the BrowseController.

Comment: Oh then what you have tried is correct. Just put all the controller.for in the setupController hook